# Automating DO droplet code deployment from Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, digital-ocean, droplet

I am planning to migrate from shared hosting to Digital Ocean and i have my complete code in bitbucket repo.
 I have launched an ubuntu 16.0.4 droplet with LAMP stack. 
Is there a way i could automate to deploy code to DO droplet for each commit to bitbucket master branch?

Comment: by "automate" you mean a fully automated and unattended deploy into your droplet anytime you push code from your dev box to your bitbucket repo?

Comment: Javier .. Automated means unattended deployment of code to droplet when a commit is made to bitbucket repo.

Comment: If that's the case, you would need to implement a webhook in Bitbucket and your server. Whenever a push is made to bitbucket on a given branch (let's say Master) , the webhook would trigger a process in your droplet(s) so the droplet makes the deploy. You can read an example here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/tutorial-create-and-trigger-a-webhook-747606432.html